# Найти самое длинное слово в файле?

Tags: python, текстовые-файлы

```
d = open('Task_HW_6.txt','r')
l = d.readlines()
string = l[0]
stringsplit = string.split()
print(stringsplit)
d = []
for i in stringsplit:
    d.append(len(i))
    e = max(d)
for j in stringsplit:
    if len(j) == e:
        print(j)
```

> Вот например текст:
> Мой график на сегодня — шестичасовая депрессия с уклоном в самобичевание, — сообщила Айран.[1] — 1

“My schedule for today lists a six-hour self-accusatory depression,” Iran said.

— У вас есть сынишка и он показывает вам свою коллекцию бабочек вместе с морилкой.
— Я отведу его к врачу, — тихо, но твёрдо ответила Рэйчел. Вновь стрелки-близнецы отклонились, но на этот раз не так далеко.[1] — 5

“You have a little boy and he shows you his butterfly collection, including his killing jar.”
“I’d take him to the doctor.” Rachael’s voice was low but firm. Again the twin gauges registered, but this time not so far.

... фальшивки стали чертовски напоминать настоящих животных, взять хотя бы
схемы, имитирующие болезни, которые встраиваются в новые модели. А настоящие
животные умирают — это один из рисков, подстерегающих хозяев. Мы просто успели уже от этого отвыкнуть, потому что видим только фальшивки.[2] — 7

... the fakes are beginning to be darn near real, what with those disease circuits they’re building into the new ones. And living animals do die; that’s one of the risks in owning them. We’re just not used to it because all we see are fakes.

Никакой поддержки, — заключил он. — Андроиды, с которыми я сталкивался, обладали жаждой жизни и видели в ней смысл куда больший, чем моя жена. Она ничего не способна мне дать.[1] — 8

No support, he informed himself. Most androids I’ve known have more vitality and desire to live than my wife. She has nothing to give me.

... он любил «Волшебную флейту». <…> Теперь Папагено, в фантастического вида балахоне из птичьих перьев, присоединился к Памине, чтобы спеть дуэт, вызывавший у Рика слёзы каждый раз, когда он его слышал или даже просто вспоминал:
Konnte jeder brave Mann
Solche Glocken finden,
Seine Fiende wurden dann
Ohne Muhe schwinden.[3]
А в реальной жизни, — подумал Рик, — нет волшебных колокольчиков, которые могут без особых усилий заставить исчезнуть ваших врагов. К сожалению, Моцарт, вскоре после того, как написал «Волшебную флейту», умер — на четвёртом десятке — от какого-то заболевания почек[2]. И похоронен был в безымянной могиле для нищих. — 9

... he loved The Magic Flute. <…> Now Papageno in his fantastic pelt of bird feathers had joined Pamina to sing words which always brought tears to Rick’s eyes, when and if he happened to think about it.
Konnte jedar brave Mann
solche Glockchen finden,
eine Feinde wurden dann
ohne Muhe schwinden.
Well, Rick thought, in real life no such magic bells exist that make your enemy effortlessly disappear. Too bad. And Mozart, not long after writing The Magic Flute, had died in his thirties—of kidney disease. And had been buried in an unmarked paupers’ grave.

Вот кончится эта репетиция, сойдет со сцены опера, умрут все исполнители и оркестранты, где-нибудь и как-нибудь погибнет последний экземпляр партитуры, бесследно исчезнет само имя «Моцарт», и прах восторжествует. Не на нашей планете, так где-нибудь ещё. Мы лишь можем на какое-то время отсрочить это. — 9

This rehearsal will end, the performance will end, the singers will die, eventually the last score of the music will be destroyed in one way or another; finally the name “Mozart” will vanish, the dust will have won. If not on this planet then another. We can evade it awhile.

— Ты будешь вынужден поступать неправедно, куда бы ты ни пошел, — сказал старик. — Жизнь в том и состоит, чтобы идти против своей природы. Рано или поздно это приходится делать каждому живому существу. Это кромешная тьма, крах любого творения, проклятье любой работы, проклятье, иже питает всю жизнь. Везде, во всей Вселенной. — 15

The old man said, “You will be required to do wrong no matter where you go. It is the basic condition of life, to be required to violate your own identity. At some time, every creature which lives must do so. It is the ultimate shadow, the defeat of creation; this is the curse at work, the curse that feeds on all life. Everywhere in the universe.”

«Время, прилив и отлив, — думал он. — Жизненный цикл. Приближается закат, и наступают сумерки. И его завершение, последние сумерки. Перед молчанием смерти». Ощущаемый в своей полноте микрокосм. — 16

Time and tide, he thought. The cycle of life. Ending in this, the last twilight. Before the silence of death. He perceived in this a micro-universe, complete.

— С тобой ничего не случится?
— Со мной ничего не случится, — ответил он. А ещё, подумал Рик, я непременно умру. И то и другое в равной степени — правда. — 20

“Will you be all right?”
“I’ll be all right,” he said, and thought, And I’m going to die. Both those are true, too.

Раньше, думал он, я мог бы посмотреть на звёзды. Много лет назад. А теперь в небе нет ничего, кроме пыли; за долгие годы никто не видел ни одной звезды. По крайней мере, с Земли. Может быть, однажды я уеду туда, откуда видно звёзды, сказал он себе. А тем временем машина набирала всё большую скорость и высоту, устремляясь прочь от Сан-Франциско, в мерзость и запустение севера. В места, куда не отправится по своей воле ни одно живое существо. Разве что почувствовав близость конца. — 20

Once, he thought, I would have seen the stars. Years ago. But now it’s only the dust; no one has seen a star in years, at least not from Earth. Maybe I’ll go where I can see stars,..
he said to himself as the car gained velocity and altitude; it headed away from San Francisco, toward the uninhabited desolation to the north. To the place where no living thing would go. Not unless it felt that the end had come.

— Боюсь, — сказал он, — что я не смогу уже перестать быть Мерсером. Вот так вот начнешь, а потом оказывается, что поздно идти на попятный. — «Так это что же», мелькнуло у него в голове, «теперь мне придется раз за разом взбираться на этот холм, делать это всегда, как Мерсер… стать пленником вечности?» — 21

“Mercer isn’t a fake,” he said. “Unless reality is a fake.” This hill, he thought. This dust and these many stones, each one different from all the others. “I’m afraid,” he said, “that I can’t stop being Mercer. Once you start it’s too late to back off.” Will I have to climb the hill again? he wondered. Forever, as Mercer does … trapped by eternity.

Comment: И еще желательно найденное слово записывать в конец капсом

Comment: Ответ, который Вам дали верен. Есть один нюанс. Может ли слово содержат знаки пунктуации (ну к примеру запятую после слова или тире как, к примеру `'стрелки-близнецы'`?

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска самого длинного слова:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  longest_word = max(f.read().split(), key=lambda i: len(i))
```

Для добавления найденного слова в конец файла в верхнем регистре:

```
with open('test.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  f.write('\n' + longest_word.upper())
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\venv\Lesson\venv\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    longest_word = max(f.read().split(), key=lambda i: len(i))
  File "C:\Users\yerko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 0: invalid continuation byte
ошибка

Comment: @Vlad попробуй убери `encoding='utf-8'` или укажи правильную, т.к. не известно в какой кодировке сохранен ваш файл

Comment: @Vlad, при открытии файла укажите корректную кодировку.

Comment: У меня самое большое слово 3 точки

Comment: почему так? может из-за чего?

Comment: вот код:
with open('Task_HW_6.txt', 'r') as f:
    longest_word = max(f.read().split())
    print(longest_word)

with open('Task_HW_6.txt', 'a') as f:
  f.write('\n' + longest_word.upper())

Comment: @Vlad какая кодировка у вашего файла?